# QGIS: Setting Active Layer in Plugin

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am creating a QGIS plugin and have a layer named "dataset_three" that I would like to activate in my Python code. My code runs, but the check mark next to the layer does not appear. Code inside my run method is below. Plugin Builder was used to generate a skeleton for the plugin code.

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        set_three = project.mapLayersByName('dataset_three')[0]
        self.iface.setActiveLayer(set_three)
```

Comment: The check box next to the layer name is the visibility indicator and not the active layer indicator. Please clarify what the desired behavior is.

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity, what does setting the active layer do exactly?

Comment: The official doc states "Set the active layer (layer gets selected in the legend) returns true if the layer exists, false otherwise." (source https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#ac42281407013002b56ff7ed422c77336)